# Hide functions between different users on GreenPlum

Tags: roles, greenplum

In GreenPlum version 6.12 we have two different users and both have segregation of roles and they cant see the tables of each other schemas but somehow they are able to view the functions presented in different schemas on which they don't have access. Is there anyway through which we can restrict users to view the functions in other schema that is not in his ownership.

Answer (score 0):

Users still can see all functions in pg_catalog.pg_proc.

```
SELECT pronamespace, proname FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc;
```

You can - somewhat - hide the content/functionality of the functions by using a compiled language. But you can't hide the existence of the functions.